# Genymotion mouse and keyboard input not working

Tags: genymotion, angular2-nativescript

I recently installed Genymotion and started the first nativeScript tutorial.  I have a issue when trying to enter text in a textfield.  When I click on the text field nothing happens.  I tried typing on my laptop's physical keyboard but still nothing.  I then enabled the virtual keyboard in the avd's settings but when I click on the text field it doesn't appear.  I can't find many similar cases online so not sure at all what to do.  i'm using a Macbook pro 13" 2015.  Any idea what could be causing this?

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out it wasn't the mouse and keyboard not working.  The issue is the screen doesn't refresh for some reason.  So if I enter something in a textfield and then minimize/maximize the window I can see the entered text...